# missing data charted within Shiny app via Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to plot a simple time series from the economics dataset from ggplot2. The app loads, then displays the chart with the correct axis, but none of the plot data is included. Any help would be very much appreciated. Best, Joe

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

df <- economics

datalst = colnames(df)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
                label = "Choose the x axis",
                datalst),
    selectInput(inputId = "y",
                label = "Choose the y axis",
                datalst, datalst[[2]])


  ),
  mainPanel(

    plotlyOutput("plot")

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    dataset  <- reactive({
      df[, c(input$x, input$y)]
    })


    output$plot = renderPlotly({

      plot_ly(dataset(), x = ~input$x, y = ~input$y,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

    })

}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: plot_ly(x = dataset()[[input$x]], y = dataset()[[input$y]],type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

Comment: @ ibusett, works great! Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped, I also posted as an answer now because I thought it could benefit others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to avoide Non Standard Evaluation, because `input$x` and `input$y` evaluate to strings, while using `plotly` as in your example requires bare column names after the ~. YOu can fix this using, for example:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

    dataset  <- reactive({
      df[, c(input$x, input$y)]
    })
    output$plot = renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(x = dataset()[[input$x]], y = dataset()[[input$y]],type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
    })

}
```

A further improvement could be to "split" the reactive in two, so that the inputs of the plot are invalidated and recomputed only when the corresponding input is changed:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

    dataset_x  <- reactive({
      df[, input$x]
    })

    dataset_y  <- reactive({
      df[, input$y]
    })
    output$plot = renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(x = dataset_x()[[1]], y = dataset_y()[[1]], type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
    })

}
```